# Creating a single column vector from a list column in R

Tags: r, nlp, strsplit

I'm currently trying to divide up a dataset of text documents (coded in UTF-8) by paragraph in R, but I'm having trouble getting them into the format I want for tidytext, which is a single column of the different paragraphs.

My data so far looks something like this:

```
list <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti.

Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.

Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.",

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti.

Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.

Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.",

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti.

Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.

Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.")
df <- as.data.frame(list)
df_spl <- str_split(df$list, "\n", n = Inf)
df_spl
```

Basically it's a large list of different vectors that have different paragraphs in them from each original row.

What I ultimately want is a single column vector with all the list items, like this:

```
 vector <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti.", "Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.", "Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti." "Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.", "Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, movet omittantur ut vel, vim an offendit prodesset. Sumo summo intellegam vel ei, dicunt persecuti vim ne. Lorem noluisse at est. Per ex postulant philosophia, ut vel amet affert tantas, pro ne consetetur scriptorem. Id mel aeque deleniti.", "Nam ut erat eligendi, pro eu minim molestie persequeris. Civibus interesset te nec, cu aeque fabellas luptatum has. Ad usu nominati tractatos. Eu voluptatum disputationi vis, alienum delicatissimi pri eu. Et molestie copiosae nam, ex vix ignota dignissim. Dico suas illum at mea, no case modus antiopam sea.", "Ius te copiosae lobortis contentiones. Est ceteros dissentiet ne, qui malis iuvaret tacimates an. Vivendo erroribus nec no. No quo corpora indoctum iracundia, mel ad mollis accusam praesent. Sit at admodum sensibus mediocrem, no pri decore nemore.")
```

I've already tried commands like cbind(), stack(), and unnest(), but none of them have gotten me that single column :(

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, try and show us a minimal working example which does not contain multiple lines of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn a list into a vector you can use:

```
unlist(df_spl)
```

Comment: Thanks! After I did this I just used as.data.frame() and got what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

We can `unlist` the `list element into a`vector`and`paste` if we need a single string

```
out <- paste(unlist(df_spl), collapse=" ")
```